# What happens if you plug an internal SATA disk into an eSATA port?

Tags: sata, compatibility, esata

What happens if you plug an internal SATA disk into an eSATA port? Assume that the hard drive has been supplied power via SATA power cable and is not an eSATA drive.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, it should work fine although you will need an e-SATA to SATA adapter cable.

I think this was answered on this question: [What's the difference between SATA and eSATA?](https://superuser.com/questions/30019/what-is-the-difference-between-sata-and-esata)

Comment: Yeah but what about my scenario. I have plugged it into the eSATA port and just want to know if I am in some way likely damaging the hard drive and/or motherboard?

Comment: @defaye do you mean you plugged it in with no adapter? out of interest, did you have to force it?  and did you see if it worked?